# Parameterized queries in Spark BigQuery connector

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to adopt [Spark BigQuery connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) and run a parameterized query, ala https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#java

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().format("bigquery").option("query", "SELECT ... WHERE x > @cutoff").load()
```

I could be mistaken, but I couldn't find any support for passing in parameters. I want to avoid string manipulation for better protection against SQL injection. What's my best way forward?

I was hoping `QueryJobConfiguration` would provide a method that inlines parameters safely into query string, but from the source code, it looks like that is not done in the client side at all (which makes sense).

I'm using Spark 3.3. It looks like Spark 3.4 added [the parameterized SQL query support](https://thedatafreak.medium.com/spark-3-4-parameterised-sql-cab01e3b6f72) so maybe that is the path forward, but for the time being I'm stuck with Spark 3.3.

Please, please tell me there's a better way than `String.format` to deal with parameterized queries in 2023...

Answer (score 0):

In [the upstream issues section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/1128), one of the authors of the project confirmed that there is no support for the parameterized queries.

While he did not suggest what the best practice is, based on his answer, I deduce that `String.format` is indeed the way to go.